# Is it possible to find camera position using 8-10 non-coplanar points, if their 3D coordinates are unknown?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I have a set of non-coplanar points with unknown 3D position (I am not limited with points number, let's say 8-10 of them), and at least 3 different views (number of views also not limited) of these points in 2D images. I have also estimation for rotation and scale for every point set on pictures that corresponds to real points, also an estimation of the euclidean distance between every two camera positions that images were taken at.

Is this data enough to find camera pose after taking another additional picture with these points (to find as precisely as possible)? If not, what are minimal additional data need to have to achieve this?

UPDATE: In this specific case I needed the function [recoverPose()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga40919d0c7eaf77b0df67dd76d5d24fa1) from [calib3d](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Depending on the algorithms (and the availability of some pre-calibration), you can obtain the relative positions of two cameras using a minimum of 5 to 8 points.

Beware that the point correspondences must be available, i.e. the points must be known in pairs.

Comment: Would you point to relevant document or right query for google? I tried 'classical bilinear problem of reconstruction camera pose position recovery' and stuff around but till now every document I found talks about 4-5 co-planar points (and they assume knowledge of 3D positions).

Comment: @stackoverflower Check the OpenCV documentation !

Comment: I think I finally understood what I really needed: the function [recoverPose()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga40919d0c7eaf77b0df67dd76d5d24fa1)  from calib3d module. Thank you for the help!